# Using Github Markdown: How to get literal Pipe into a table

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I am producing a cheat sheet using Unix commands and markdown. When I use a pipe in a Unix command I get an extra column.  I can't seem to find the character to give a literal `|`. The pipe between `ls` and `wc` gives 4 columns.

Example:

```
| # | Command | Description |
|:--|:--------|:------------|
| 1. | ls | wc –l | count number of files in a directory. |
```

**Tried:** backslash, forward slash, single backtick, triple backtick, surround it with 2 spaces, **,`<code> </code>`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding backslash works:

```
| # | Command | Description |
|:--|:--------|:------------|
| 1. | ls \| wc –l | count number of files in a directory. |
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and for some reason it does not work on Atom editor.

Comment: It works on github, see https://github.github.com/gfm/#backslash-escapes. I believe it is Atom's fault not to show it properly.